# ClassNotFoundException at time of Jboss-eap-6 to Jboss-eap-7 migration

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

I know I am asking this too late but I need help below.
My Current application is running fine with Jboss-eap-6x. now I am trying to deploy the same code to Jboss-eap-7.3. but I am getting ClassNotFoundException for my class(Ex:- java class written by the developer, not the predefined class).
My code is deploy as .war file.

Comment: Have you read the migration guide? https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/migration_guide/tools_to_assist_in_migration. Simple webapps might run unchanged on EAP 7, but anything complicated will need some thought.

Comment: The migration tool may help. That stack trace would also be helpful as there is not much to go on here.

Comment: My issue happens due to some unuse code and unuse Jar file. I clean all the code. now it's working